# Upgrade fails for 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I updated and upgraded all packages on my Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus) in preparation for a release upgrade to 18.04 (Bionic).

I have checked other posts, but my problem is a little different.

I continually get the following message when I run `do-release-upgrade`:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]
Err Upgrade tool
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Fetched 819 B in 0s (0 B/s)
WARNING:root:file 'bionic.tar.gz' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

I do not know why the system is choosing that IP address and I don't know how to change it.

When I point a web browser at  http://185.125.190.36, I see that it does not have the bionic release, Ubuntu 18.04.

I have tried entering various things in `/etc/apt/list.sources` but nothing works.
For example,

```
deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic main
```

was suggested but the `do-release-upgrade` ignores it.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I don’t think you can upgrade from 16.04 any more as it’s end of life. I think you’ll have to do a fresh install (and would be sensible to go for 22.04LTS to give you maximum life from the os).

Comment: You can upgrade from an EOL release but not in the usual way. A fresh install is a better choice. Also 18.04 is EOL in a few weeks the 5 years is up. Better to do 22.04 or at least 20.04

Comment: Even to do an upgrade and update for 16.04 would not have worked as it is gone. Not sure what it is you did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/167115)

Comment: I think the only difference is that if it tells you that `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` does not exist, then you should install `update-manager-core` instead.

Comment: I've performed an `do-release-upgrade` from *xenial* (16.04) to *bionic* (18.04) within the last week; however my location in the world probably differs (*and this can be important unless all upgrades are applied; all upgrades now requiring ESM to be enabled now depending on geolocation due to expired certificates in some areas*). Early in the process two tarballs are downloaded (inc., bionic.tar.gz) that direct the upgrade; the site does not come your sources.list files but the [upgrade tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-upgrader). Ensure you've applied all upgrades!